# Java is asking for a return statement, but I'm returning "something"

Tags: java

So I have a simple method that takes two inputs a String and an array list of strings. I try to search for the given string in the given array list and if it's found I return it, if not I return a statement saying that it wasn't found
here's my code:

```
String findWord(String word, ArrayList<String> list){
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        if(word.equals(list.get(i)))
            return word;
        else
            return "Word not found";
}
```

I also tried:

```
String findWord(String word, ArrayList<String> list){
    String myString = null;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        if(word.equals(list.get(i)))
            myString= word;
        else
            myString = "Word not found";
    return myString;
}
```

but the return value is always null.

Comment: check if length of List > 0? if not it will return null

Comment: are you sure `list.size` is `>0`?

Comment: Please ask a consistent question. It is either 1) "always returning null" or 2) a syntax (compiler) error that "is asking for a return statement". It is *not both*. Please ask a question about *one*, and make sure the *title* and the *body* agree and include *actual* error messages, if any.

Comment: The first block won't compile. The compiler will notice that if the list is empty neither the 'if' nor 'else' statements will ever be executed and it will complain about not seeing a return statement for every possible execution of your code

Comment: did anybody notice second example given in question works if list has values?I think question is not valid

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman Yeah, I actually just copied it over to a dummy class and it totally works, the array must be either empty or full of null values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try,

```
String findWord (String word, ArrayList<String> list) {
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (word.equals (list.get (i))) {
          return list.get (i);
      }
   }
   return "Word not found";
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this, try: list.contains(yourString); It will return true if the list contains your string.

Answer (score 2):

The list must be empty, otherwise it wouldn't fall through the if/else.

You can simplify the method to

```
String findWord(String word, ArrayList<String> list) {
    return list.contains(word) ? word : "Word not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows that a for loop can have 0 iterations, and won't accept you not specifying a return statement after the for loop, to support the case that the loop is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you will not be allowed to compile first one.(if the list size is 0, it will return nothing although has the return type "String"). For second, I did a little modification. Otherwise it will return "Word not found" if there are not-matching words after the matched once in the list `ArrayList`. The only case you get a null is when the list is empty.

```
String findWord(String word, ArrayList<String> list){
   for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
      if(null != word && word.equals(list.get(i)))
         return word;
   return "Word not found";
}
```

Anyway it is much efficient if you use list.contains(Word) as Delfino Gomes mentioned.